# Русс. СКРЕСТИ у Фасмера

Tags: этимология

**Заметил любопытную вещь**:
В словаре Фасмера этимология таких однокоренных русских слов, как **СКРИП**, **СКРИПКА**, **СКРИЧИГАТЬ**, **СКРИЖАЛЬ**, **САНСКРИТ**, **СКРОБАТЬ** и т.п. никак не выводятся из **древних латыни или греческого**.
Это странно.
Дело в том, что Фасмер приводит древнюю латынь в родственники только лишь по отношению к русс.**СКРЕБУ**.
Он упоминает лат. **SCROBIS** В ЗНАЧЕНИИ "**ЯМА**".

Замем Фасмер приводит **ЯМУ,** не понятно.
В латинском есть прямые слова: **SCRIBO**, **SCRIPSI**, **SCRIPTUM** = писать, вырезывать(письмена), описывать; **SCRIBA** = писец, секретарь, переписчик;
**SCRIBATUS** = должность писца; **SCRIPTIO** = писание; письмо,
**SCRIPTITO** = часто или много писать; **SCRIPTOR** = писец, секретарь,
переписчик, писатель; **SCRIPTUM** = письмо, сочинение, книга;
**SCRIPTURA** = писание, шрифт, записывание, сочинение; **SCRIPTURA**
= **Священное Писание**. Всё это - латинские слова, о которых **Фасмер умолчал**. Но на каком основании? Опять помешали законы языка?

Латинские же: **SCABREO** = быть шероховатым, **SCABRATUS** = сделанный шероховатым, **SCABRITIA** = шероховатость, шершавость, негладкость, **SCABER** = шероховатый, грубый, **SCABIES** = шероховатость, шершавость, **SCABIOSUS** = шершавый, шероховатый; **SCARIFO** = делать насечки, надрезать, **SCARIFATIO** = надрезывание, насекание; **SCRUPULUS** = острый камешек
или песчинка, беспокойство, внутренняя тревога, **SCRUPUS** = острый
камень; **SCIRPO** = плести, сплетать, связывать тростником, **SCRIPSI** = опутывать, **SCIRPEA** = плетенка, плетеная корзина, **SCIRPEUS** = плетеный, **SCIRPUS** = тростниковая сеть;
**CON-CREPO** = скрипеть, издавать громкий звук. Др.-инд. **САНСКРИТ** - от **СКРИПЕТЬ**, в значение царапать, писать (**САН+СКРИТ**, т.е. **Священное Писание**) и т.д.

Опять случайное совпадение? Или **ЯМА** больше подходит для объяснения русс. **СКРЕБУ**, чем **SCRIBO** (писать)?

Comment: Не, я столько не выпью.

Comment: Название САНСКРИТ (saṃskṛtā) считается недавним. И правильно считается. Индийская культура, вопреки, рассказам историков, довольно молодая. В отношении ведической культуры, это примерно 600-700 лет. И это -самое большее. Более реальная дата зарождения "древней" Индии - 14-16 вв.от Р.Х.
Др.-инд. sā́nu - "вершина, высота, острие" перешло из русс. САН (напр., сановник - о духовном или светском чине)

Слово САНСКРИТ двусоставное. Точно так же, как, например, Санк-Петербург, SANCTI-FICO и т.п.  

продолжение - см. далее...

Comment: В латинском находим SANCTE = свято, SANCIO = узаконивать, твердо устанавливать, SCRIPTUM = писать, SCRIPTIO = писание; письмо,
SCRATCH = царапина.

Корень САН имеет во всех языках значение - СВЯТО, СВЯТОСТЬ, ОСВЯЩЕННОСТЬ. 
Слово СКРИТ (СКРИПТ) - от русс.СКРЕСТИ, СКРЯБАТЬ пером, давшие, кстати, большой куст слов во многих европейских языках.

Тексты на САНСКРИТе - священные тексты "древне"-индийского духовенства. Отсюда и название.

Другого, более аргументированного трактования пока нет.
Приведите, если знаете.

Comment: см. комментарии ниже, спрятанные

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Др.-инд. САНСКРИТ - от СКРИПЕТЬ, в значение царапать, писать (САН+СКРИТ, т.е. Священное Писание)

Извините, это бред. Впрочем, откуда дровишки? Это так, потому что не может быть по-другому? Любой САН — это священный? Ну-ну...

Comment:  Название – санскрит – образовано из слов "сам" и "крита", что можно перевести как "само-созданный". Кстати, сравните крита с английским create. Ну а "сам" и в переводе не нуждается.Это мнение Петра Семилетова, с которым согласен и я.

Comment: Собственное мнение — это хорошо. Но хотелось бы, чтоб оно было еще и просвещенным, нет?

"Сан" похож на "сам" — этого достаточно? Вряд ли.
Кстати, а Петр Семилетов — это кто, губернатор острова Борнео? Почему его мнение такое авторитетное?

Comment: http://bookz.ru/authors/petr-semiletov/semil108/1-semil108.html
Взаимно: а что, губернатор Борнео в авторитете?
Вариантов много.
В буквальном переводе слово "санскрит" означает "культура", а также "освящённость", "благородность". Это литературный вариант одного из древнеиндийских языков, относящийся к индоевропейской языковой семье. "Санскрита" – так звучит слово "санскрит" на самом санскрите. В русский язык слово "санскрит" пришло из хинди.
Само слово «санскрит» означает «обработанный, совершенный»
Ну и как с этим быть? пять позиций и все в разнобой.
особенно  saṃskṛtā-литературный

Comment: ребенку ясно, что это эпитеты к языку, а не этимология. Как у нас великий и могучий. Другое дело Девангари--тут есть разборка по корням, бог и город.
"Само же название «санскрит» достаточно недавнее, в течение многих веков этот язык называли просто वाच (vāc) IAST или शब्द (śabda) IAST «слово, язык», расценивая его в качестве единственной возможности для ведения речи. Несколько метафорических наименований, таких как गीर्वांअभाषा (gīrvāṇabhāṣā) IAST «язык богов» указывают на его исключительно религиозный характер"
Когда недавно, не уточняется. Но насилие англичан несомненно.

Comment: >> Ну и как с этим быть? пять позиций и все в разнобой.
>> ребенку ясно, что это эпитеты к языку, а не этимология

Ясно. Надо просто разрубить гордиев узел. Само-созданный, и всё. )))))))

Comment: А до того потугальцев.  А в португальском  священое писание  - santo
  escrita.  вот и этимология санскрита.  Сан-сокращение, а сам -- искажение. Чисто европейское происхождение слова. Скрипт.

Comment: Рубится узел элементарно, с привлечением словаря.:)

Answer (score -1):

Скребу

скребу скребу́ скрести́, скресть, укр. скребу́, скребти́, блр. скреба́ць, цслав. оскребѫ, словен. škrébati, škrẹ́bljem; с др. ступенью чередования: словен. škrábati, чеш. škrab "царапина", škrábati "царапать, скрести", слвц. škrаbаt᾽, польск. skrobać, в.-луж. škrabać, н.-луж. škrabaś. Родственно лит. skrebė́ti, skrẽbа "шуметь, шуршать, шелестеть", skrãbalas "побрякушка, погремушка", ãtskrabai мн. "отходы", лтш. skrabt, skrabu "скрести, скоблить, чесать, царапать", skrabstît "скрести", ср.-нж.-нем. sсhrареn (*skrapôn), др.-исл. skrapa "царапать, вычеркивать", англ. sсrаре "скрести", лат. scrobis "яма"; см. Цупица, GG 157; Траутман, ВSW 267; Зубатый, AfslPh 16, 412; Буга, РФВ 65, 311; 75, 145; М.–Э. 3, 884; Торп 456; Вальде–Гофм. 2, 500. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

в латыни  crepitus-  одно из значений-скрипеть(без начального s).

А похоже,  что латинская яма не при чем.   scrobis,  синоним - laci. а в русском синоним - лаз.
в немецком, датском яма-grube
в шведском - grop 
а албанском-gropë
в литовском -duobė, оно и понятно, что гроб из дуба.
а в болгарском могила - гроб
а в английском могила - grave
в исландском могила - gröf
в немецком - Grab
в нидерландском могила-graf
синонимы могилы--в переводе дают слова: важный, серьезный, тяжелый. Объект похорон имел вес в обществе.
А в латыни могила -sepulchrum, по корням если: se pul
chrum--себя красивая битком.
звучит гордо--братская.
В свете последних раскопок в Риме, очень актуально.
 Ну и датировка таких захоронений очень интересна.

Comment: Спасибо за хороший ответ!
Я чувствовал, что ЯМА у Фасмеровского SCROBIS - ни при чем.